# Ruby(Chef) - Convert hash into array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, chef-infra

I have a chef cookbook with a hash.

```
foo = { 
  'herp' => 42, 
  'derp' => 84 
}
```

I have a LWRP resource (bar) that can only take arrays

```
iis_root 'some string' do
  bar []
end
```

How can I convert 'foo' into an array so it can be used in the resource 'bar'

Looking for something like this:

```
[ "herp=42","derp=84"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
bar = foo.map{ |e| e.join("=")}
=> ["herp=42", "derp=84"]
```

Comment: oh, you are right , doesn't need to use `to_a`, thanks for reminding me .

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the hash and turn it into an array like so.

```
ary = Array.New
foo.each do |key, value|
  ary << key + "=" + value
end
```

This will create the array you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map):

```
foo.map { |key, value| key + "=" + value.to_s}
=> ["herp=42", "derp=84"]
```

Answer (score 1):

OscillatingMonkey answer correct, but with few changes:
For topic starter, this code doing exactly what you need.

```
bar = Array.new([])
foo.each do |key, value|
  bar << key + "=" + value.to_s
end
=> ["herp=42", "derp=84"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `map` with string interpolation:

```
foo.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }
#=> ["herp=42", "derp=84"]
```